# My Apache site is suddenly 403'ing me and everyone

Tags: php, linux, apache, vps

So starting a few days ago my Apache site, hosted on a VPS box, has suddenly started throwing 403 to anyone and everyone. I can log into the box just fine Selinux is still disabled like it should be and the permissions for Apache are all as they should be.

Interestingly, I'm guessing around the time my site started throwing 403s, my box started pumping out a constant outgoing of about 80BPS, see below

[image: Traffic]

Initially I assumed my box was compromised/shelled and being used as part of a DDoS network but that seems unlikely given the relatively low amount of outgoing.

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe better ask on serverfault.com?

Comment: Will do, thank you.